# Nice links in comments

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

How do I insert a nice looking link where the displayed text is not the URL ([this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1914/3073) as opposed to this: [h​ttp://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1914/3073](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1914/3073)) in a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make links in comments (this works in posts and chat, too), use the format:

`[here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)`

For more information on formatting comments, click on the "help" link to the right of the comment-entry box. For even more information, click on "Learn more..." there, or just click [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to go to the FAQ page on comment-editing.